# Native graphic card function

Tags: c++, c, graphics, assembly

If i understand correcty, the graphics card are programmed to display 2D&3D graphics and these cards have native functions, but because these functions are obsolete and hard to use, we nou use drivers, that makes the programmers life easier.

Now, my question is that if there are some native graphics card function tutorials and if these are universal, that works on every graphics card or differ from one to another like ASM language does. And if there exists tutorials, can i use C language or C++ or i need to have asm knowledge ?

Comment: why not use OpenGL or DirectX?

Comment: I guess most of them are VESA compliant.

Comment: " these functions are obsolete " ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way GPUs are programmed (at least the advanced functions) is typically through either MMIO (as in, an address in virtual memory corresponds to a register in the GPU instead of actual DRAM), or more often, through command buffers (as in, a chunk of memory is used to store commands for the GPU, that the GPU reads sequentially.

Now, those commands and registers are very hardware dependent (even within a single hardware vendor): see for example [ATI R600](http://www.x.org/docs/AMD/R6xx_3D_Registers.pdf) registers. They are not "universal" *at all*.

Those types of interfaces are what driver developers use to implement the DirectX and OpenGL APIs that typical programs use.

Probably the best source of "tutorial" for that level of programming are the open source drivers in linux.

Comment: But i think that these function are still used in creating Operating Systems Graphical User Interfaces, am i right? Or there are special tools for OSdev?

Comment: No, the OS too uses the driver.

Comment: DWM (windows gfx) likely uses the umd interface, that is very close to DirectX (so just use DX). I believe most linux 3d gfx renderers use OpenGL directly, but I'm not an expert there. the OS uses the drivers for sure for its own rendering.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good reason there are now more standardised ways of talking to the graphics subsystems in computers. Unless you have a specific platform in mind I'd suggest you stick to using the standard API's I.e. go through OpenGL or DirectX.

Answer (score 2):

> If i understand correcty, the graphics card are programmed to display
>   2D&3D graphics and these cards have native functions, but because
>   these functions are obsolete and hard to use, we nou use drivers, that
>   makes the programmers life easier.

in a sense yes, although not obsolete, it is all about abstraction.

there are several tutorials on the web, for instance for OpenGL there
is [nehe.gamedev.net](http://nehe.gamedev.net) DirectX has also a number of tutorials, just
use your favorite search engine although OpenGL has the big advantage
of being portable.

Generally you can use either C or C++ and do not need to know any ASM if you
do not have some extreme requirement.